# Java method flow state design

Tags: java, design-patterns

Hello My code will following a sequence process.

Every part possible got a fail situation.

And I want to know the process is blocked by which part.
So there is a state to know the process is fail on which method.

```
public class MethodSequenceDesign {
    public static final int STATE_WAIT = 0;
    public static final int STATE_A_RUNNING = 1;
    public static final int STATE_A_FAIL = 2;
    public static final int STATE_B_RUNNING = 3;
    public static final int STATE_B_FAIL = 4;
    public static final int STATE_C_RUNNING = 5;
    public static final int STATE_C_FAIL = 6;
    public static final int STATE_END = 7;

    static int status = STATE_WAIT;

    public void start() {
        if (!methodA()) {
            status = STATE_A_FAIL;
            return;
        }
        if (!methodB()) {
            status = STATE_B_FAIL;
            return;
        }
        if (!methodC()) {
            status = STATE_C_FAIL;
            return;
        }
        status = STATE_END;
    }
    public boolean methodA() {
        status = STATE_A_RUNNING;
        String str = "do some operation in method A";
        System.out.println(str);
        return randomBoolean();

    }
    public boolean methodB() {
        status = STATE_B_RUNNING;
        String str = "do some operation in method B";
        System.out.println(str);
        return randomBoolean();
    }
    public boolean methodC() {
        status = STATE_C_RUNNING;
        String str = "do some operation in method C";
        System.out.println(str);
        return randomBoolean();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MethodSequenceDesign method = new MethodSequenceDesign();
        method.start();
        System.out.println("Final state = " + status);
    }
    public boolean randomBoolean() {
        Random random = new Random();
        return random.nextBoolean();
    }
}
```

I have my example code here:
https://ideone.com/4Rw0Zs

My question is, is there a design pattern that I could beauty my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For error handling, use exceptions:

```
public class MethodSequenceDesign {


    public void start() {
        if (!methodA()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("methodA failed");
        }
        if (!methodB()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("methodB failed");
        }
        if (!methodC()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("methodC failed");
        }
    }
    public boolean methodA() {
        String str = "do some operation in method A";
        System.out.println(str);
        return randomBoolean();

    }
    public boolean methodB() {
        String str = "do some operation in method B";
        System.out.println(str);
        return randomBoolean();
    }
    public boolean methodC() {
        String str = "do some operation in method C";
        System.out.println(str);
        return randomBoolean();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MethodSequenceDesign method = new MethodSequenceDesign();
        try{
            method.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStacktrace();
        }
    }
    public boolean randomBoolean() {
        Random random = new Random();
        return random.nextBoolean();
    }
}
```

Comment: Even better if methodA, methodB and methodC just throw the exception when there is an error.

Comment: Instead of adding a message to RuntimeException, you could also specify exceptions by yourself, e.g. a common approach is to extend RuntimeException. This can be helpful in some situations.

Answer (score 0):

State, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern, could be what you’re looking for here.

*Edit*

One solution to your specific problem could be to implement the methods as lambda expressions implementing an interface that you add to a collection class and then loop over the collection and execute each of them until all has been executed or one returns a failed state.

Comment: Please provide a concrete answer in reference to the question. The OP has internet access, so he can find Wiki links on Google; links are not answers.

Comment: The question was simply if there is a design pattern to use, not how to implement it or such. I think I have given a concrete answer or rather a pointer to a concrete answer.

Comment: But is it really fitting his case? It does not seem he really does state transitions to change the behavior, he is just doing error handling. What he really should be doing is probably using exceptions.

Comment: Thanks. I had study state pattern, but it did not meet my question, My process is  steps by steps, my concern is if I have 10 or more  methods to do similar things, is there a better way to control my normal/fail state.

Comment: Ok, so I misunderstood the question to be if there was a known design pattern for this but you're asking more for a design solution